# Monotonicity and Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true *in general* that if $B \subseteq A \implies \lvert B \rvert \leq \lvert A \rvert$, where $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ denotes cardinality? My intuition tells me that it would be natural to expect this to be true but it has failed me before.

Comment: "*But it has failed me before*" care to elaborate on this?  Your intuition in general has failed you?  Or your intuition about this specific situation has failed you?

Comment: Just in general when it comes to set theoretic concepts. For a specific example, Banach-Tarski threw me for a serious curveball when I first read about it.

Comment: Fair enough, Banach-Tarski throws everyone for a loop, but that has more to do with measure theory and the concept of unmeasurable sets which are in general quite strange.  It is a good bit beyond elementary set theory.  As an aside, the extension of your problem into measure theory, the answer is affirmative as guaranteed by the definition of a measure.  $E\subseteq F\implies \mu(E)\leq \mu(F)$ for $\mu$ an inner,outer,pre, or ordinary measure.

Comment: Yeah actually my intuition for the monotonicity of the cardinals came from the fact that $B \subseteq A \implies \mu(B) \leq \mu(A)$, especially when you consider the counting measure. I just wasn't quite sure whether it extended to uncountable sets but reflecting on it now, it seems more obvious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true by definition of cardinality. Remember that "$\vert B\vert\le\vert A\vert$" means *exactly* that there is an injection from $B$ to $A$; if $B\subseteq A$, we can take the inclusion map as such an injection.

---

I'm being a bit glib here when I talk about "the definition of cardinality." Depending on whether the axiom of choice holds or not, defining cardinality can be easy or a bit tricky. (Either way, the *relation $\vert X\vert\le\vert Y\vert$* is easy to define, as I have above - and see the final paragraph, below.)

So let me say a short bit about what "cardinality" means (and by "short", I mean "about twice as long as the rest of this answer"). This may safely be considered tl;dr, but you may also find that it helps clarify matters.

*With* the axiom of choice, every set is in bijection with an ordinal. We now define the cardinality of a set $X$ to be the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that there is a bijection from $X$ to $\alpha$. Cardinalities are ordered by the ordering on ordinals. If $X\subseteq Y$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are the least ordinals in bijection with $X, Y$ via the maps $g, h$ respectively, it's not hard to show that $\alpha\le\beta$ - letting $i:X\rightarrow Y$ be the inclusion map, we have an injection of ordinals $f:\alpha\rightarrow \beta$ given by $f=h\circ i\circ g^{-1}$. Now we can't have $\alpha>\beta$ since then by Cantor-Shroeder-Bernstein we'd have that $X$ is in bijection with $\beta$, contradicting the assumption on $\alpha$. So we must have $\alpha\le\beta$, since the ordinals are linearly ordered, so $\vert X\vert=\alpha\le\beta=\vert Y\vert$.

*Without* the axiom of choice, the definition of cardinality becomes more complicated: the ordinals no longer provide "representatives" of each cardinality. Indeed, such a nice choice of representatives may not exist without choice: see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53770/defining-cardinality-in-the-absence-of-choice). We can define the cardinality of a set in a manner similar to Frege:

- Frege identified e.g. "$2$" with "the set of all two-element sets."
- This doesn't work in $ZF$ (the collection of two-element sets is a proper class, not a set), but we can use [*Scott's trick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick): we let $\vert X\vert$ be the set of sets which are in bijection with $X$ *and have minimal rank* amongst such sets, where "rank" refers to the [cumulative hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).

Note, however, that $\vert X\vert$ *is not a set in bijection with $X$* - rather, it is a set *of sets* which are in bijection with $X$. Expressions like "$\vert X\vert\le\vert Y\vert$" need to be interpreted accordingly - they now mean "For every $A\in\vert X\vert$ and $B\in\vert Y\vert$, there is an injection $i: A\rightarrow B$."

Note that the picture of comparing cardinalities via injections is more fundamental, at the end of the day, than a specific definition of what "cardinality" is. This is an important point: with some exceptions (e.g. "countable"), relative cardinality tends to be more important mathematically than absolute cardinality.

Comment: Note that in the choiceless setting, terminology gets a bit tricky: depending who you talk to, "cardinal" can either mean "cardinality, whether well-ordered or no" or "[initial ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Initial_ordinal_of_a_cardinal)" (essentially, "cardinality in the choicey-sense of a well-orderable set"). So e.g. on one reading "the cardinals are well-ordered" is trivially true in ZF, whereas on another it is equivalent to the axiom of choice.